# On Click of of a ImageView Change the Background of the Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

On click of the ImageView i want to change the background of the layout .How can i do this i have created the selector that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item 
                    android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bar" 
                    android:state_pressed="true"/> 
            <item 
                    android:drawable="@drawable/gray_bg"/>
    </selector>
```

**XML is**

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="reviewItineary"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />
```

Comment: will u comment why u r down voting this question or u don't understand ...

Comment: use this code in imageview click myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable. blue_bar);

Comment: i want to change the background of the complete layout in which this image view there

Comment: u can't use selector for this u have change the background of layout and the image view in imageview click

Comment: have got the answer i post an answer for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mylayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);//Your layout instance

imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
  imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable. blue_bar);
                     mylayout.setImageResource(R.drawable. blue_bar);
               }
     });



}
```

Comment: `myImgView` is definitely not defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Create selector like this**

**image_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bar" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bar" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bar" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_bg" />
```

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="reviewItineary"
            android:background="@drawable/image_selector.xml"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />
```

Comment: will it change the background of the Layout

Comment: ok you want to change background of other layout right? so not need to selector you can directly use method layot.setBackgroundDrawable()

Answer (score 0):

```
    lLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);//Your layout instance

    bookButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
bookButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v==bookButton){

    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));//to change the color
    lLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drwableItem);//drawable object
    lLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bckResource);//resource
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the background of the imageview without setting any color filters to the imageview itself like so:

```
    button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private Rect rect;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(),  v.getBottom());
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
         if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                        backButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Programatically you can do it as shown below:

```
bookButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bookButton);

    public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

        bookButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                setActivityBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This code is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: on click of the imageview i am starting a new activity so will it work se in the xml i have mentioned on click

Comment: No,in that case this will not work. In your case you can Attach the color id with the intent and start the activity. And onCreate of that activity, fetch the color id from intent and use the above setActivityBackgroundColor() function. Surely it will work I'll edit the answer if you want.